# Converting GIF to MOV IOS

Tags: ios, swift, gif, mov

In my IOS App I want to Convert **GIF to MOV/Video**.

I don't Know Where To start.

I researched much and finally I know is I have to use **ImageMagic** API for this But don't Know How to Apply It.

Is there any other way except using ImageMagick???

Please Guide me In this Case That how to do so. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please Write Down Reason for Down voting my Questions..

Comment: You need to show what you have attempted as of now. You can't only ask question especially when answer can be very broad.

Comment: Here, I want to get only Idea because I don't know How to apply it. I haven't started it yet @PankajGaikar

Answer (score 0):

You can Get sequence of images from that GIF. And then you need to convert those all into .png and then you can play that frames as mov.

That's the nice solution. For both steps libraries and tutorials are available